# How to search for line with ConstructionTime(10); in a file and get the number assigned to a variable?

Tags: cmd, find, command-prompt

The command

```
find /i "constructiontime" file.cfg
```

outputs the line

```
constructiontime(10);
```

I want to read in this line and get just the number assigned to a variable independent on what is the number value.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using command **FOR**:

```
@echo off
set "ConstrutionTime="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "constructiontime" file.cfg') do set "ConstrutionTime=%%I"
if defined ConstrutionTime echo The construction time is: %ConstrutionTime%
```

**FOR** runs the command line as specified in round brackets in a separate command process started with `%ComSpec% /C` in background and captures everything output to handle **STDOUT** of this command process which is the output of **FIND** if the string could be found in any line.

After termination of started command process the captured output is processed by **FOR** line by line. Empty lines are ignored as well as lines starting with a semicolon which is the default end of line character.

**FOR** splits all other lines into substrings using `(` and `)` as delimiters because of `delims=()`. The first substring is in this case `constructiontime` which is of no interest. The second substring is `10` which is the string of interest. The third substring would be `;` which is also not of interest. For that reason `tokens=2` is used to assign the second substring to specified loop variable `I`.

The value of loop variable `I` is assigned to environment variable `ConstrutionTime` which is used on next command line to show the result on running this small batch file from within a command prompt window.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`