# How to set different variables for each result of a search in a file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

This is an add-on to my previous question:

[How to search for line with Effective("flyer", 100%); in a file and get the number assigned to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769862/)

The code I have so far is:

```
@echo off
set "Effective="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=%%) " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "flyer" file.cfg') do set "Effective=%%I"
if defined Effective echo The effective value is: %Effective%
```

This code takes number `100` from line `Effective("flyer", 100%);`
in `file.cfg`.

But what to do if there are two lines with `flyer` in `file.cfg`?

I have already tried it and this code takes the last flyer value `50`.

```
Effective("flyer", 100%);

Effective("flyer", 50%);
```

How to choose between them?

The first code block containing first flyer is:

```
CreateWeaponType("jda.weapon.aatower")
{
  Style("Projectile");

  MaxRange(96);

  HorizAngle(90);
  HorizSeparation(180);
  VertAngle(0);
  VertSeparation(120);
  TurnRate(90);
  Speed(100);
  Fixed(1);


  Damage()
  {
    Amount(10);

    Effective("infantry", 0%);
    Effective("vehicle", 0%);
    Effective("structure", 0%);
    Effective("flyer", 100%);

    Effective("mine", 0%);
  }

  Projectile("jda.proj.aatower");
  Delay(1);
  FirePoints()
  {
    Add("HP-Fire1");
    Add("HP-Fire2");
    Add("HP-Fire3");
    Add("HP-Fire4");
  }
}
```

The second flyer is in:

```
CreateObjectType("jda.exp.aatower", "Explosion")
{
  MapObj()
  {
    Mesh();
    GenericFX()
    {
      Add("ExplosionObj::Explode", "jda.fx.aatower.exp");
    }
  }
  ExplosionObj()
  {
    Damage()
    {
      Amount(16);

      Effective("infantry", 0%);
      Effective("vehicle", 0%);
      Effective("structure", 0%);
      Effective("flyer", 50%);
      Effective("mine", 0%);
    }
    AreaInner(4);
    AreaOuter(4);
    Persist(0);
  }
}
```

How to set a different variable for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ('FindStr /I "Effective(\"flyer\"," "file.cfg"^|Find /V /N ""')Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims=,%% " %%C In ("%%B")Do @Set "flyer%%A=%%C"
@Set flyer[
@Pause
```

The bottom two lines are included just to show you the variables with their respective value strings.

You could also split the long line at the top into three lines to help maintain reasonable line lengths for readability:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ('FindStr /I "Effective(\"flyer\"," "file.cfg"^
 ^|Find /V /N ""')Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims=,%% " %%C In ("%%B"
)Do @Set "flyer%%A=%%C")
@Set flyer[
@Pause
```

Please note that this answer provides no way of determining which percentage belongs with which particular section of the `.cfg` file:

Comment: How to make it search for Amount(10) or any Word(54) too? (I want to get the numbers)

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /F "tokens=2 delims=%%) " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "flyer"^<file.cfg') do set /a count+=1&set "Effective[!count!]=%%I"
echo %count% items found
if %count% gtr 0 set effective[
```

The critical line here is the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line which invokes `delayed expansion` where the syntax `!var!` results in the value of `var` as it might change within a `for` loop.

Hence, as `count` starts at `0`, should the appropriate line be detected then `count` is incremented and then effective[*value of count*] is set to the appropriate value.

After the `for` loop finishes, the count is shown (obviously, this line is optional).

The final `set` will simply display the value(s) that are `set` in the environment for values beginning `effective[` - but only if `count` is greater than 0.

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774185/3074564) and [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774291/3074564) are already wonderful solutions. So there is nothing more to contribute by me, except if you are interest in only the first `flyer` value. In this case a small modification of original code can be used to exit the loop with a jump to a label below the loop after having assigned first `flyer` number from `file.cfg` to the environment variable `Effective`.

```
@echo off
set "Effective="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=%%) " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "flyer" file.cfg') do set "Effective=%%I" & goto HaveValue
:HaveValue
if defined Effective echo The effective value is: %Effective%
```

`find.exe` outputs an empty line and and the line `---------- FILE.CFG` which is the reason for using **FOR** option `skip=2` to skip the first two lines to avoid assigning `FILE.CFG` to environment variable `Effective`.

It is of course also possible to rewrite the entire code on being interested only in first `flyer` value.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=%%) " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /I "effective.*flyer" file.cfg') do set "Effective=%%I" & goto HaveValue
echo No line with "flyer" found in "file.cfg"
goto :EOF

:HaveValue
echo The effective value is: %Effective%
```

This code uses `findstr.exe` instead of `find.exe` which does not output header lines. And a very simple regular expression search string is used now instead of just literal search string `flyer`.

But the provided batch files by **Magoo** and **Compo** are already fine on being really interested in both `flyer` numbers.

Comment: Additional information, `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe` will output `---------- FILE.CFG` etc. as mentioned above, but that can easily be eliminated by using redirection, `%__AppDir__%find.exe /I "flyer"<file.cfg`. _Obviously inside your `For` loop, you'd need to escape the redirection character, `%__AppDir__%find.exe /I "flyer"^<file.cfg`_